# Justified grid with unknown width and number of child elements

Tags: css, grid, block, justify

I am trying to do a perfect justified grid with a unknown number of child elements and a unkown  width.
Each elements contains a different word.
The space between the words in `<div></div>` must be the same.

```
<div class="grid">
    <div>nhdsgf</div>
    <div>sdfghfgjsdf</div>
    <div>xcfgcvb</div>
    <div>dfhhfg</div>
</div>

.grid
{
    font-family:"arial";
    font-size: 12px;
    width:250px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#46d246;
    text-align:justify;
}

.grid > div
{
    display:inline-block;
    padding:3px;
    background: #228f22;
    margin:2px;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Here is the example : http://jsfiddle.net/CeBdP/

Comment: There's no way to do that sans JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

This maybe a little bit of a hacky solution using CSS3 however if you add 'font-size:0;' to the parent div, you can get a better result. It may break is some older browsers. I would recommend doing it using javascript to get a much more robust outcome. I am not sure what you are going to create but I would take a look at http://masonry.desandro.com

```
.grid
{
font-family:"arial";
width:250px;
padding:10px;
background:#46d246;
text-align:justify;
font-size:0;
}

.grid > div
{
display:inline-block;
padding:3px;
background: #228f22;
margin:2px;
color: #fff;
font-size: 12px;
}
```